# node.js - How to extract a substring between 2 slashes?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to extract the domain name from a string which is like "http://www.domain.com/bla324". The result should be "www.domain.com".

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a regular expression :

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/bla324",
    match = url.match(/\/\/([^\/]+)\//)[1];
if (match) {
    var host = match[1];
    ...
}
```

You may also use the dedicated and standard node package [url](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html) :

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/bla324",
    urlObject = require('url').parse(url),
    host = urlObject.host;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the browser, I would use the a element :

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/bla324",
    a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = url;
var host = a.host;
```

In node, the package [url](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html) like @dystroy said.